# How to handle EF 4.3.1 setting Modified a Rowversion Row

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3

Say we have:

```
public class Driver
{
    public int driverID { get; set; }
    public byte[] stamp { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string prename { get; set; }
}
```

Now in short I`m facing this kind of situation.

```
 ...
 var myDriver = myCustomDBContext.Drivers.AsNoTracking()
                                         .Where(d => d.driverID == driverID)
                                         .SingleOrDefault();
 ...
 myDriver.name = "John";
 myDriver.prename = "Lennon";
 ...
 myCustomDBContext.Drivers.Attach(myDriver);
 myCustomDBContext.Entry(myDriver).State = EntityState.Modified;
 myCustomDBContext.SaveChanges();
 ...
```

And the result is

```
 The column cannot be modified because it is an identity, rowversion or 
     a system column. [Column name = stamp]
```

Is there any method which could force an Update on a detached entity, or a workaround for this *rowversion* column not to be set as Modified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you didn't have specified the `stamp` property as a rowversion in your model and it is just a binary field. You can specify it with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Driver>().Property(d => d.stamp)
    .IsRowVersion()
    .IsConcurrencyToken(false);
```

The code above is for the case when you don't want to have the `stamp` property as a concurrency token. (A rowversion is a concurrency token by default, so you have to disable it explicitly.) If you want to have it as concurrency token, then you can use with Fluent API...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Driver>().Property(d => d.stamp)
    .IsRowVersion();
```

...or with data annotations:

```
[Timestamp]
public byte[] stamp { get; set; }
```

This should prevent EF to write an UPDATE for this property.

**Edit**

If you use Database-First strategy the `[Timestamp]` attribute does not work. This attribute is only for Code-First development.

When you use Database-First the connection string contains a metadata section refering to the EDM defined in the EDMX file:

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl
                          |res://*/Model1.ssdl
                          |res://*/Model1.msl;
                          ...
                          ..."
```

If Entity Framework finds this section in the connection string it doesn't use data annotations on model properties nor does it process any code in Fluent API (`OnModelCreating` isn't called at all). Instead it loads the mapping definitions from the embedded and compiled EDMX file.

That means, if you want to define the `stamp` property as a concurrency token you *must* do this in the EDMX file. In XML it would look like this:

In SSDL section:

```xml
<Property Name="stamp" Type="timestamp" Nullable="false"
          StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed" />
```

In CSDL section:

```xml
<Property Name="stamp" Type="Binary" Nullable="false" MaxLength="8"
          FixedLength="true"
          annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed"
          ConcurrencyMode="Fixed" />
```

You can also define this in the model designer in Visual Studio: Mark the `stamp` property in the entity in the designer surface, go to the Properties Window and set "Concurrency Mode" to "Fixed" (and also set the "StoreGeneratedPattern" to "Computed").

You can also remove the metadata section from the connection string. But this effectively means that you switch from database first to code first development. Then all attributes and Fluent API will be respected, but not any definitions in EDMX anymore.

Comment: Marking the property as [Timestamp] isn`t solving anything. The problem relies within the `DBContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;`. It marks the stamp property as Modified and during `DBContext.SaveChanges()` it build`s the *dynamic-sql* which updates the column [stamp] in the DB. This is a guess cause of SQLCE I have no profiler to back it up.

Comment: @CiobanuIon: For SQL Server this is not true. EF doesn't send a SQL which updates a column of a property marked with `[Timestamp]`, instead its value is included in the WHERE clause for optimistic concurrency checking. Did you test that it doesn't work? Which version of SQLCE are you using?

Comment: I`m using SQLCE4.0.0.0. Now that I tested if concurrency is working, it`s not. With usual non-detached entities, the update is happening, the [stamp] value is incrementing but the concurrency is not happening. This is unexpected. I`m having a database first case. Generated POCOclases from EF4.x DbContext Generator and decorated them with DataAnnotations. Really unsure where to look now. On the previous matter, my guess was if I can`t set Modified to the whole entity I set only some properties as Modified, and update worked. But hard-coding for every property is not a proper solution.

Comment: @CiobanuIon: Do you have the same error message as before or another error?

Comment: When I`m using usual non-detached entities I get no error at all! If I modify a row through raw-sql, I would expect an *DBConcurrencyException* when updating the entity from my DBContext, but nothing. The Error message I got earlier only when I explicitly set `DBContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;` after attaching it to the context.

Comment: @CiobanuIon: I have some doubt that data annotations are consumed at all when you are using database first. (They are called *Code First* data annotations and processed during model discovery. But if you use Database First the model is defined in the EDMX file.) It is possible that you have to mark the stamp property as concurrency token in the model designer in Visual Studio.

Comment: With Database first, it was generated an ObjectContext and the entities indeed couldn`t be decorated with data annotations, we used interfaces which described the annotations, and MetadataType attibute with the entity partial class. And extended ObjectContext constructor to register an type description provider for EntityObject class to ensure the consumption. 

But when we decided to move to DBContext and added an Code Generation Item to the EDMX - EF4.x DbContext Generator. Which generated the DBContext and Entities. We moved the annotations from interface to the class. They work.

Comment: @CiobanuIon: See the Edit section in my answer above. The data annotations do *not* work to define EF model metadata when you use database-first. They *do* work when you use them for other purposes, like validation, binding to UI, etc. Those components might process the attributes but EF doesn't - unless you use code-first.